# Bayesian linear regression with continuous and binary covariates

Tags: regression, bayesian, terminology, binary-data, continuous-data

I am interested in learning more about applying Bayesian linear models for covariates some of which are continuous and some are binary.

What is the appropriate terminology for such models so that I can search online for literature related to these models?

Thanks y'all.

Comment: There is nothing that special about the nature of the covariates. Bayesian regression and Bayesian linear models should be generic enough entries to find papers and books on the topic.

Comment: Whether the variables are continuous or binary should be irrelevant to the process of performing a regression.

Comment: @Xi'an Niel D I have seen some papers where the authors transformed the discrete covariates to continuous using log transformation, wonder why they did that ?

Comment: Could you provide a link to a paper?  [Discrete-time transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_transforms#Discrete-time_transforms) maybe..

Comment: if you have discrete variable and take the log, then you have again discrete variable that assumes only some values on $\mathbb{R}$. I don't see the difference

Comment: @NeilD http://books.google.com/books?id=AALhk_mt7SYC&pg=PA208&lpg=PA208&dq=Ramsey+and+Schafer+%281997%29+BIRD+EXTINCTION&source=bl&ots=XwF0FF11Mi&sig=xISiyALa7QXLo91eooP-aK1Oz5E&hl=en&sa=X&ei=R3uCVJKOCc_8yQTTm4GoBg&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=Ramsey%20and%20Schafer%20(1997)%20BIRD%20EXTINCTION&f=false

Comment: @niandra82 you may be right, I am having a hard time understanding what you mentioned,

Comment: @Tyrone Williams The definition of discrete random variable is: a variable that may assume only a countable, and usually finite, number of values. Just for example let assume that your variable assumes only the values $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. If you take the log than you variable can assume values in $\{log(1),log(2),log(3),log(4),log(5)\}$ that is again a countable set, i.e. it is again a discrete variable

Comment: The section that you cited explains why they took the logarithm.  It was to remove the skew.  It had nothing to do with discrete versus continuous.

Comment: @TyroneWilliams Tom has your answer.

Comment: @TomMinka,@Niel thats perfect

Answer (score 2):

This one needs to be put to bed.

> I am interested in learning more about applying Bayesian linear models for covariates some of which are continuous and some are binary.

As people have pointed out in comments, there's no distinction - linear regression is linear regression whether your x's are continuous or binary. This applies to Bayesian linear regression as well.

If they were *all* binary, you might call it Bayesian ANOVA perhaps, but it's still also Bayesian regression.

> What is the appropriate terminology for such models so that I can search online for literature related to these models.

It's all just Bayesian linear regression.

(There are also a number of questions on site that discuss aspects of the topic.)